# .NET Socket Connect IPv6 error

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, ipv6

I've started to get an error after I've installed a new network adapter (although it's disabled) on the previously-working code:

```
     Dim MyipAddress As IPAddress
     Dim MyipAddresss() As IPAddress
     Dim remoteEP As IPEndPoint

     MyipAddresss = Dns.GetHostEntry(sServidor).AddressList

     For Each MyipAddress In MyipAddresss
        remoteEP = New IPEndPoint(MyipAddress, iPuerto)

        Sock = New Socket(MyipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)

        Sock.ReceiveTimeout = 0
        Sock.SendTimeout = 0
        Sock.ReceiveBufferSize = 8388607
        Try
            Sock.Connect(remoteEP)
            bConectado = True
            Exit For
        Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.Print(ex.Message)
        End Try

     Next
```

The input parameters, sServidor="192.168.1.10" and the iPuerto=54321. This code worked until a new network device was added (I think; it's the only change I remember on the system). The error raises at the Sock.Connect line, it's in spanish but it goes like this:

SocketErrorCode=10060

"An error was produced on the connection attepmpt due to the connected part did not respond after a period of time, or an error was produced on the established connection...etc"

I've noticed that "MyipAddresss", ather the DNS.GetHostEntry, it's a 1 item list with an IPv6 format; so I've tried changing the parameters of New Socket(); I've tried InnerNetwork and InnerNetworkV6 instead of AddressFamily with no success.

I've also found that disabling the TCP/IPv6 protocol from the adapter's properties get my code to work:

[image: This mode connects OK]

But, since I can't ask clients to disable protocols that they may need, this solution is not an option.

PS: With the IPv6 protocol enabled (not like in the picture), a PING using the IPv6 version of the sServidor (the IPv6 address I get wit the GetHostEntry) reaches destination. Also, the IPv6 address corresponds to the same adapter as the IPv4 sent as parameter (according to the IPCONFIG)

I appreciate any help.

Regards!

Comment: Where are you getting the IP addresses from? That code seems to be missing, and it is probably important here.

Comment: sServidor and iPuerto are parameters received by the function. They are correct as I've checked debugging. Thanks Michael for your answer!

Comment: I'm concerned about `MyipAddress` and `MyipAddresss`. Your question doesn't show the code which shows how these are set.

Comment: Sorry @MichaelHampton, I didn't understood you the first time. I've edited and corrected the question; I've skipped the line. Thank you very much!